# Change Wordpress User Profile Photo By Id

Tags: wordpress

Attempting to change several of my users profile pics (via code).

I am using Ultimate Members & WP User Avatar but have not come to a good resolution as yet.

I really need a function that can be passed the user ID and a URL (of profile pic.

something on the line of

```
function set_avatar_url($avatar_url, $user_id) {
    global $wpdb;
    $file = upload_product_image($avatar_url);
    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($file['file']);
    $attachment = array(
        'guid' => $file['url'],
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($file['file'])),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file['file']);
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $file['file']);
    wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data);
    update_user_meta($user_id, $wpdb->get_blog_prefix() . 'user_avatar', $attach_id);
}
```

set_avatar_url('https:/mysite.com/Logo-test2.png', 5);

Am I asking too much?

Comment: yes. you are asking a bit too much. We are here to help you with the code you write not write code for you. So, do a bit of research, make at least an attempt and then come back here and ask us to help with your code in case it does not work. This is how SO works :)

Comment: Done this before.

Comment: and what was the result of this?

Comment: It unfortunately does not work, but unsure why.

Comment: Where did you add this code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't change wordpress user avatar programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57227664/cant-change-wordpress-user-avatar-programmatically)